# make4ht \boxed rendering wrong when using MathML

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, make4ht, mathml

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\boxed{A} \boxed{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

When I compile using pdflatex I got the two boxes side by side, but when compiling with something like `make4ht test.tex "mathml, mathjax"` only the first box is rendered right.
This only occurs when using mathml, if I compile using `make4ht test.tex "mathjax"` everything is right.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, with mathml the boxes are wrong and there is a warning `[WARNING] domfilter: .../texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/mrow) [char=816]` during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that something went wrong from this warning message during the compilation:

```
[WARNING] domfilter: /home/mint/texmf/scripts/lua/LuaXML/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/mrow) [char=847]
```

This means the generated HTML code contains some severe error and may look wrong.

The generated HTML + MathML code is following:

```html
   <table class="equation-star"><tr><td>
<!--l. 5--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="block" class="equation">
<menclose notation="box"><mrow>   <mi 
>A</mi>                                                             </mrow></menclose><menclose notation="box"><mrow><!--l. 6--><p class="indent" >   <mi 
>B</mi>                                                             </mrow></menclose>
</math></p></td></tr></table>
```

The problem is this tag inserted into MathML: `<p class="indent" >`.  It shouldn't  be there. Fortunatelly, we can block it easily by the following configuration for `boxed`:

\Preamble{xhtml}

```
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{boxed}
   {\ifmathml \Tg<\a:mathml menclose \a:mathml notation="box">\Tg<\a:mathml mrow>%
    \else     \HCode{<span class="boxed">}\fi\IgnorePar}
   {\ifmathml \Tg</\a:mathml mrow>\Tg</\a:mathml menclose>%
    \else \HCode{</span>}\fi}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It reuses the original TeX4ht code. The only change is that we use the `\IgnorePar` command in the second argument. It should prevent the insertion of the spurious `<p>` tag.

The result is correct with this change:

```html
  <table class='equation-star'><tr><td>
<!-- l. 5 --><math class='equation' display='block' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><mrow>
<menclose notation='box'><mrow>   <mi>A</mi>                                                             </mrow></menclose><menclose notation='box'><mrow>   <mi>B</mi>                                                             </mrow></menclose>
</mrow></math></td></tr></table>
```